# Android Wear: Installing to multiple wear devices

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm building a phone app with direct connection to a wear app running on several wear devices.  The wear app will run on several wear devices at the same time and will share data to a single phone app.
I'm following the Android [guidelines](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) for co-packaging the wear and phone apps in a single package.
My question: can the wear app be auto-installed on multiple wear devices?  If so, can you recommend how?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the same as on a single device, basically. The Android Wear app on the user's phone will push your wearable app to all connected devices.

I have my primary phone linked to two or three Wear devices as a matter of course, and apps get pushed to all of them. It's really no different.